# Stuck Oldest unsent transaction in db mirroring

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, mirroring

I am seeing some very strange behavior in db mirroring

For one of the databases, during the weekend when rebuild index job ran on the principal, it generated around 60 GB log.

Now its been 2 days and mirroring is not in sync. ON mirror it always showing synchronizing  and seems to be DC in between.

When i monitor further i see oldest unsent transaction is always stuck at 2:10:07:20 and increasing with time while unrestored log starts with 60 GB goes to 0 and then starts showing again with 60 GB still pending.

**Update@**

I see couple of times every 5 min there is a **Disconnected** state logged in `Mirroring_state column` for all the databases now on the instance

Can someone please guide what can be an issue here and what to check?